# Updating from 2.1.3 to 2.1.4 on magento

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, composer

Magento:

I am trying to update the magento via Web setup and its giving me error

Check Component Dependency
We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail

Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

The requested package magento/product-comunity-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Potential causes:

A typo in the package name
The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

For additional assistance, see component dependency help .

Then i tried the CLI methods too, but this is the error i am getting
[root@eme ~]$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.0].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 requires composer/composer 1.0.0-beta1 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.0.0-beta1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

My Composer.json

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.1.3",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.4",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/product-comunity-edition": "2.1.4"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with your `composer.json` file?

Comment: added composer.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `"magento/product-comunity-edition": "2.1.4"` line from your `composer.json` *(note the typo in the word "community")*.

Make sure you also remove the trailing comma `,` from the previous line to maintain valid JSON syntax.

Your final require block should end up like the following:

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.4",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha"
},
```

Once this is fixed up, you should be able to run `composer update` to install v2.1.4

Comment: hi danny, this composer has been created by magento, any way i am using this solution to check if this solve our program

Comment: Thanks bro the typo was the mistake. I had fixed it via editing the same via nano editor